# Command "where python" does not return anything in PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

As the title implies, when I am trying to `where python` **from PowerShell** it returns nothing. No errors or something... it just goes to a new line (as if I pressed "Enter")

On the other hand, CMD Prompt successfully returns the following:

```
C:\Users\User>where python
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

`python --version` successfully returns the version in **both** pwsh and cmd. Can someone figure how to fix `where` in powershell ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In PowerShell, `where` is an alias for the `Where-Object` cmdlet.

To explicitly invoke `where.exe`, include the `.exe` extension:

```
PS ~> where.exe python
C:\Users\mathias\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

---

If you want to figure out why a certain command name doesn't resolve as expected, use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command):

```
PS ~> Get-Command where

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           where -> Where-Object


PS ~> Get-Command where*

CommandType Name                  Version      Source
----------- ----                  -------      ------
Alias       where -> Where-Object
Cmdlet      Where-Object          3.0.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
Application where.exe             10.0.19041.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\where.exe
```

---

As an amusing bonus, your newfound knowledge of `Get-Command` might prove `where.exe` obsolete - as `Get-Command` evidently has the ability to locate executables as well :)

```
PS ~> Get-Command python
    
CommandType Name       Version Source
----------- ----       ------- ------
Application python.exe 0.0.0.0 C:\Users\mail\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```